# Passing a Native Window Handle to a DLL in Java

Tags: java, canvas, jna

To explain the problem I guess its the best to explain (simplified) what I want to do.

There is a device(camera). The API to this device is provided by a native DLL. One function inside this DLL needs a Native Window Handle to draw the captured image directly in the application. The solution with C# would be to pass a `PictureBox.Handle` to this function. However in Java the drawing component is an `awt.Canvas`. The earlier implementation for this problem was to get a peer of this Canvas which is deprecated since JDK 1.1. Also I don't know if this apporach ever has been working. Therefore they are two questions:

1. Could the deprecated approach really have been working?
2. Is there any other possible solution to pass a window handle to the DLL?

This is the signature for the function inside the DLL:

```
int draw_func(..., const void* window,...);
```

And this how the problem was solved(or maybe not) before:

```
long lhwnd = ((sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer)._canvasPictureBox.getPeer()).getHWnd();

Pointer HWndPtr = new Pointer(lhwnd );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNA provides a method to obtain the component's native peer, [`Native.getComponentPointer()`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Native.html#getComponentPointer-java.awt.Component-), which you can use to initialize a `HANDLE` object from JNA's `platform.jar` or pass in directly.

Comment: Infinite THANKS! It purrs like a kitten :D. Pointer p = Native.getComponentPointer(_canvasPictureBox); HANDLE hndl = new HANDLE(p); To pass it to the native function I need just call hndl.getPointer() et voilla! The image is on the canvas.